# Shell script nested loop (while within for loop) does not work

Tags: bash, shell, sh

My shell script, It executes its inner loop correctly, but only execute its outer loop once.

Please kindly check my script, why it does not work.

OS: Amazon EC2 Linux

I created shell script, to delete files, from a directory, with filenames, 
that are not exist in my created TXT file.

```
for entry in "/home/ec2-user/upload/upload/*"
do
    exist=false

    file="/home/ec2-user/upload/requiredjpg.txt"
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if [ "$line" = "$entry" ]
        then
            echo "same"
        else
            echo "not same"
        fi
    done <"$file"

    echo $exist
    if [ $exist = false ]
    then
        echo $exist
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression `"/home/ec2-user/upload/upload/*"` is interpreted, literally, as string `/home/ec2-user/upload/upload/*`. Obviously, you expected it to be expanded to an array of paths matching the wildcard expression. But, in double quotes, the asterisk character has different meaning, -- it is only used in [shell parameter expansions](https://gnu.huihoo.org/bash-2.02/html_chapter/bashref_3.html#SEC29) (which is not present in the expression in question.)

What you really need is [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html). In order to activate it, you simply need to put the asterisk character outside the double quotes:

```
"/home/ec2-user/upload/upload/"*
```

Note that you don't need the double quotes in this particular string, since there is no any special character in it that needs to be escaped (quoted).

Comment: but this part: if [ "$line" = "$entry" ]

it always consider both variable as not equal, even if it is equal,

anyone know the reason?

Comment: @Hendra, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but the expression `if [ "$line" = "$entry" ]` compares strings and returns true if and only if the strings are equal. The code in the question iterates (*supposed to*) all files in `/home/ec2-user/upload/upload/` directory, then *compares the file paths with each line of text in /home/ec2-user/upload/requiredjpg.txt*. It is just possible that you really wanted to compare `"/home/ec2-user/upload/requiredjpg.txt"` (as a string) with `"$entry"`; in that case, you don't need the `while` loop.

Comment: @Hendra, also, I would suggest printing more information, not just `same` and `not same`, but somethiing like `printf '%s equals %s\n' "$line" "$entry"`. Alternatively, you can turn on debugging mode with `set -x` command.

Comment: @Hendra, as an aside, you check the value of `$exist` variable, but do not set it anywhere after initialization. Also, you might want to `break` the loop when "the file is found". And yes, if you are only searching for specific path/filename, then the `find` command would be much more convenient, e.g.: `find /home/ec2-user/upload/upload/ -type f -name 'requiredjpg.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

There is misplaced 'do', in the inner loop. The 'if' statements should come under it.

```
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    if [ "$line" = "$entry" ]
```

Comment: Sorry about that. OP originally pasted an image which I transcribed to text. I missed the `do`. It is there in the original code.